# ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration - is it possible to open and edit app.config?

Tags: c#, wpf, configurationmanager

I tried to find some information in topic:
[EntityConnection error The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224993/entityconnection-error-the-specified-named-connection-is-either-not-found-in-the)

Now I found another solution - to open .config file and create key in connectionstrings.
But my question is that - Entity Model add connectionstrings to app.config file. ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration open myApplication.exe.config file.

- is it possible to change that application will use myApplication.exe.config ?
- or maybe there is way to open app.config file and add connectionString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OpenMappedExeConfiguration` in combination with `ExeConfigurationFileMap` to specify the file name:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
   new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = "your file path here" }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks but two more questions. I wasn't really good at this paths. Exe file is in folder\bin\debug\file.exe, app.config is in folder\app.config. So now when I copy config file (because app.config isnt part of exe?) and exe to another pc i should change path, right? @EDIT 
 
..or I can use "Copy always" in app.config ?

Comment: Ehh, problems again.. Now after I copy connectionString directly from working copy, it says that data source= is not valid value in connectionstring..